# Help identify a 1960's comic book about an older space craft saving more modern spaceships

Tags: story-identification, comics

I'm looking for a fondly remembered comic book for my husband.  He recalls a comic book from when he was a child - (Late 1950's to mid 1960's) where an older astronaut has a space craft that is considered by the younger set to be outdated and useless.  During the story, while traveling in outer space, he sees a group of alien invaders coming towards the newer fleet.  I believe he sends a warning to his comrades, but because they are traveling faster than the speed of light, they cannot see the approaching invasion.  In the end the older man and his "outdated" space craft save the day.

I'd love to find a copy of this as a Christmas gift.  Thanks for any help that can be offered on this quest.

Comment: Did the twist have something to do with the "older" ship having defences that were considered unnecessary in the newer ships due to the technology having "moved on"?